# Symfony 4 - How to .on( "select") and upgrade a counter in entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

in my entity i have a counter of view 
it begin to 0 and ++ each time doctrine call entity

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="compteur", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $compteur;
```

i can use this function

```
public function UpCompteur()
{
    $this->compteur = $this->compteur + 1;
}
```

How to auto-use this function each time i "select" the entity with doctrine ?

i know that i can add this function in repository each time i do a request but there is not a better possibility ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a [lifecycle callback](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-callbacks).

In your case you need to call your function on `postLoad` event.

> The postLoad event occurs for an entity after the entity has been
>   loaded into the current EntityManager from the database or after the
>   refresh operation has been applied to it.

It should look like the following:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Entity {
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad
     */
     public function UpCompteur()
     {
         $this->compteur = $this->compteur + 1;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Drkey this is final solution

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Entity {

    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad
     */
    public function UpCompteur(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $this->compteur = $this->compteur + 1;
        $em->persist($this);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

Really useful !